# Why is the number of lines showing as 0 when I also print the lines out but works fine when its just the line count

Tags: c, file-io

So both the code to print the lines from the txt file and the code to count the lines in the txt file work fine when the other is commented out but when i try to have both work only the code that comes first works e.g. if i put the code to print out the lines first, the line count is always zero. However if i put the code to count the lines first, the number is correct but the lines from the txt file are not printed :S

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    const int SIZE = 128;
    char line[SIZE];
    FILE *srcFile;
    int c;
    int count = 0;  // Line counter (result)

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("No command line arguments given!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    srcFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (srcFile == NULL)
    {
        perror("\n*** FILE OPEN FAILED ***");
    }
    else
    {   
        printf("\n*** FILE OPEN SUCCESSFUL ***\n\n"); 
    }

    while(fgets(line, SIZE, srcFile) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    for (c = fgetc(srcFile); c != EOF; c = fgetc(srcFile))
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            count ++;
        }
    }

    if(c != '\n' && count != 0) 
    {   
        count ++;
    }

    printf("The file %s has %d lines\n ", argv[1], count);

    fclose(srcFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pleased don't spam with unrelated language tags. If you're programming in C then don't add C++.

Comment: As for your problem, after the `fgets` loop, where is the file-pointer positioned? I suggest you read about the [`rewind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind) function.

Comment: You need to reset the internal file position to reread the lines so as to count them. In C, you may be interested in the fseek function. Look it up

Comment: You must [rewind or fseek](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) the file at the start between two loops.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is meant by the, sorry first semester doing this.

Comment: Actually, if you're just counting lines, why can't you do it in the same loop where you do `fgets`? You *do* know that `fgets` reads a *line*?

Comment: Thanks so much, used the rewind function and everything is working fine now, though curious how the code fragment would have to look to include the line count int the same loop as the print lines

Comment: also literally second question posted so dont know how to mark top answers or anything :S

Comment: Look for checkmark to the left of the answer, you can click it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick overview of how working with files is done in most programming languages:

When you *open* a file in a program you obtain a **handle** to that file. What the handle representation is depends on the language. In `c` it is the `FILE` structure. The handle contains - among other things - a **file position indicator**. Every read and write to that file through this handle happens at that position. Usually a read/write operation advances this file position indicator. Think about it: how do consecutive reads *know* to each read where the previous one left? You don't provide an argument to the read function telling it where to read from. You just "say" `read`. What happens is that each `read` call reads at the file position indicator and then advances this indicator, thus when the next `read` happens the handle has an updated file position indicator.

So the solution to your problem is - as mentioned in the comments - to *put* this position indicator to the beginning of the file. In `c` this can be done with [rewind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind).

---

> curious how the code fragment would have to look to include the line
>   count int the same loop as the print lines

Simple. Pseudocode:

```
line_count = 0
while (read line successful)
{
    print line
    increment line_count
}

print line_count
```